# jQuery Countdown animate only which is changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm trying to use the following plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I'm trying to animate (with CSS) the block only where numbers are changed: every second the seconds block, every minute the minute block, etc.

The problem is that the plugin will append all the counter HTML again into the container on each second. So i should need a `.changed` class or something on block which have been currently changed in the current second.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Now we know your problem, but what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("your_counter").countdown({
    /* your settings */
    onTick: tickHandler
    }

var tickStorage = [0,0,0,0,0];
function tickHandler(data){
    $(".countdown-amount").each(function(index){
        if(this.innerText !== tickStorage[index]){
            $(this).parent().addClass("changed")
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("changed")
        }
        tickStorage[index] = this.innerText
    })
}
```

Perhaps a little something like this?